# Can we add Null to the Array list?

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

please see the below, I am bit confused here:

```
   Dim myQueue
   Set myQueue= CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

   myQueue.add("over")
   myQueue.add("") 'is this valid statement
   myQueue.add("") 'is this valid statement
```

Now Suppose an array(6)=(a,d,,,e,t)

```
   For I=0 to Ubound(array)-1

    myQueue.add(I)

   Next
```

Now the Arraylist  `myQueue` would contain the Non-Null values(i.e. a,d,e,t) or all the array element?

**CODE** *I just tested and result is good for now*

```
Option Explicit

    Dim myQueue,i
    Set myQueue = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    'Dim Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary

    myQueue.Add("jumped")
    myQueue.Add("over")
    myQueue.Add("")
    myQueue.Add("")
    myQueue.Add("dog")
    myQueue.Add("Cat")

    i=0
    Do While myQueue.Count > i

      MsgBox(myQueue(i))
    i=i+1
    Loop

    MsgBox("Capacity=" & myQueue.Capacity & "Count:" & myQueue.Count)

    myQueue.Remove("dog")

    MsgBox("Capacity=" & myQueue.Capacity & "Count:" & myQueue.Count)

    i=0
    Do While myQueue.Count > i

      MsgBox(myQueue(i))
    i=i+1
    Loop
```

Thanks

Comment: why don't you add a particular special character to define a null than just wandering with nulls.... AND when you always ask **CAN WE DO, CAN WE ADD....** do you every run that code to see if it gives an error when you do so?

Comment: `Dim Set ...` anyhow seems an invalid construct ... no?

Comment: @MikeD i just edited my description,so now please tell me. I wrongly pasted it previously!

Comment: in Excel VBA (2010) your `myQueue.Add("")` is syntactically correct, but not each `.Add` creates a new item. make a test sub and inspect the behaviour of the myQueue object in the Locals window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding a `null` into the list, will you be `validating for this null` in the future? Meaning what's the purpose of adding the null?

If answer is yes, then you may add a special character, then validate for the special chracter that `masks` the null, and omit or take whatever action as it deems.

If answer is no, then yes you can pass a null into the list. It is not adding. Or just leave it empty.

PS:

**AS PER MY COMMENT**: It's great that if you could test out adding nulls into the arrayList to see whether you will be bugged by an error or not**

Comment: "Sir" when you told,I should do.. and I did it.No bugs,things are OK! :-)